# Finding quotations in a text

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I actually deal with the problem of finding quotations (i.e. "this is a quotation") in larger texts of different languages, mostly German and English. Unfortunately there are several ways to fill text in quotation marks (marks differ in various languages). I tried `StringCases`, but this did not work as expected:

```
test = "This is a „real“ test, even wit a „really longer“ citation!"
```

then:

```
StringCases[test, "„" ~~ __ ~~ "“"]
(* {"„real“ test, even wit a „really longer\
“"} *)
```

which is correct, but not what I intended. I also tried with `RegularExpression` but could not get it to work as expected, so I got back to my "handmade" `StringPosition` which gave immediate success ;-)

```
pos = StringPosition[test, {"„", "“"}]
```

and

```
Partition[First /@ pos, 2]
```

finally:

```
StringTake[test, %]
```

This works, but I think this should be no problem with a `RegularExpression` or `StringCases`, only, ... I could not get it to work. Can anyone give me a hint (maybe it is obvious - but I do not see it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `Shortest` is the key here:

```
str = "This is some text with \"quotations\" in «various styles», \
including \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]double curly quotes\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]."

StringCases[str, 
 Alternatives["\"", "'", "«", "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]"] ~~ 
   Shortest[x___] ~~ 
   Alternatives["\"", "'", "»", "\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]"] :> x]
```

> {"quotations", "various styles", "double curly quotes"}

Note this makes no attempt to pair the open and closing quotations so will not work with nested quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed the `Shortest`.. I always though that there must be simple solution, but I wouldn´t have found this.